# Exchange HA Cert handling

Tags: exchange

If you have two Exchange 2010 servers acting as a client access, hub transport and mailbox server.  One as a primary online server and the other as a warm or hot spare scenerio.  How at the certs handled if you move traffic from the online server to the spare?

Comment: 1. Install the certificate on both servers. 2. How do you propose that you're going to keep email in sync between the two servers? Are you using a DAG?

Comment: What method are you using to make this "warm" or "hot" spare? That sounds weird. There's DAG for the mailbox role, built-in routing for HT, and load-balancing for CAS. Are you doing something else?